# Magento 2 - Import csv with ssh

Tags: magento2, import

is it possible to import csv in Magento 2 from ssh command?

Comment: even i want to know is there any option in magento 1

Comment: you can use magmi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the list of `bin/magento` commands, there is no one to trigger the CSV import. As all shell commands in Magento 2 are executed with `bin/magento`, the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your own command in magento 2 and mimic what happens in magento's backend.

I did it this way and it works well.

Take a look at 
*magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Validate.php*

for the **validation part** and

*magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Start.php*

for the **consumer**.

In order to initalize the importer you have to pass some **configuration data**.

Here's an example:

```
[
        "entity"                    => "catalog_product",
        "behavior"                  => "append",
        "validation_strategy"       => "validation-stop-on-errors",
        "allowed_error_count"       => 10,
        "_import_field_separator"   => ",",
        "_import_multiple_value_separator" => ",",
        "import_images_file_dir"    => ""
    ]
```

I hope this gives you a good starting point.

Michele

Answer (score 1):

There is a module with which you can integrate a corresponding shell command: https://github.com/cedricblondeau/magento2-module-catalog-import-command

You can simply install it with composer and enable it like this:

```
composer require cedricblondeau/magento2-module-catalog-import-command
php bin/magento module:enable CedricBlondeau_CatalogImportCommand
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Usage is pretty straigth forward:

```
php bin/magento catalog:import -i pub/media/import -b add_update catalogdata.csv
```

where catalogdata.csv is in your magento webroot directory and `-i` designates the directory where your images are stored.

It's still working well with Magento 2.3.2. I've been using it since ver. 2.2.2, hope it helps.